# Loopback.js Instantiate PersistedModel without Database Transaction

Tags: loopbackjs

Is it possible to instantiate a PersistedModel subclass without having to wait for the database transaction to go through? I know ModelClass.create({...}) will return a promise which resolves when the instance is created, but is there a version of that which just returns an unsaved ModelClass instance?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can use `Model.find(function(err, model) {
  model.property = 'hello';
  // your custom logic here
  model.save();
})` if you want to edit a particular model.

Comment: Does that create a new instance or retrieve an existing one?

Comment: Retrieve an existing one, but you can modify the existing properties etc and save it again.

Comment: Yes but I am trying to create a new model and NOT save it.

Comment: I believe the build() function may be relevant but it isn't mentioned anywhere in the docs

Comment: Sounds counter-intuitive. You're trying to create a persisted model that is not persisted? What is your use case?

Comment: I am trying to pull a list of the properties on the model, though I suppose that does sound like something a static method would provide. Any idea what method on the PersistedModel class provides a list of its properties?

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head. Feel free to dig through https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/lib/persisted-model.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do it in one request if that's what you're thinking. Probably best to use:

```
Model.create({...}, function(err, instance) {
  // do you custom logic here
  instance.save(); // then save it again here
});
```